# Sorting out directories by searching certain file extension

Tags: directory, sort, basename

Let say, I am in a directory A, under A there are many folders (B, C, D, etc.), and in each folder there is a file "*.out" and sub-folders. I want to run a script from A which will look for the text "index123" in *.out file and print out all corresponding folder names.

Here is my sript:

```
#!/bin/sh  
FILES=home/A  
grep --include=\*.out -rnw $FILES -e "index123" | while read file; do  
str1="FILES/$(basename $file)"  
echo $str1
done
```

This shows error.

N.B. This can be done by "find" in one line code, but why while loop shown shows error?

Comment: What is the error? And why do you try to access `/../A`?

Comment: Why not just `grep index123 */*.out`

Comment: Or `grep -l` to get the filenames

Comment: @Kusalananda, it can be anywhere, say, /home/A

Comment: @JeffSchaller is grep `index123 */*.out` before while `|` ? If so, it shows no such file or directory

Comment: @Akand No, `grep -l index123 */*.out` is the complete command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per from the post [find a file through particular search in while loop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/457284/find-a-file-through-particular-search-in-while-loop) one of solutions can be as follow by using the `while` loop:

`#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r d;

  grep -q "index123" "$d" && dirname "$d"|awk -F'/' '{print $2}'

done < <(find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -name "*.out")`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a directory structure like the following:

```
A
|-- B
|   |-- file1.out
|   |-- file2.out
|   `-- file3.out
|-- C
|   |-- file1.out
|   |-- file2.out
|   `-- file3.out
|-- D
|   |-- file1.out
|   |-- file2.out
|   `-- file3.out
`-- E
    |-- file1.out
    |-- file2.out
    `-- file3.out
```

The issue with your code is that your `grep` will produce output that looks like

```
./B/file1.out:2:some data which includes the word index123
./B/file2.out:2:some data which includes the word index123
./B/file3.out:2:some data which includes the word index123
./C/file1.out:2:some data which includes the word index123
./C/file2.out:2:some data which includes the word index123
./C/file3.out:2:some data which includes the word index123
./D/file1.out:2:some data which includes the word index123
./D/file2.out:2:some data which includes the word index123
./D/file3.out:2:some data which includes the word index123
./E/file1.out:2:some data which includes the word index123
./E/file2.out:2:some data which includes the word index123
./E/file3.out:2:some data which includes the word index123
```

That is the output of

```
grep --include=\*.out -rnw . -e "index123"
```

with `A` as the current directory.

You will then try to run `basename` on these individual lines, which fails since `basename` takes at most two arguments (a pathame and a suffix to strip from that pathname). GNU `basename` will complain about an "extra operand" while BSD `basename` will complain about incorrect usage.

---

`grep` will show you the names of the files (only, i.e. not the complete line that matched) when you use it with the `-l` flag.

This means that your script may be replaced by the single command

```
grep -w -l "index123" */*.out
```

This will give output on the form

```
B/file1.out
B/file2.out
B/file3.out
C/file1.out
C/file2.out
C/file3.out
D/file1.out
D/file2.out
D/file3.out
E/file1.out
E/file2.out
E/file3.out
```

I added `-w` as you used in your `grep` command line. `-n` (for numbering lines, which you are also using) may not be used together with `-l`.

Judging from your code, this is what you want.

If you need just the folder names, then do

```
$ grep -w -l "index123" */*.out | sed 's#/[^/]*##' | sort -u
B
C
D
E
```

All of this assumes that `A` is the current working directory, but you said that this was the case in the question so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks! As I mentioned in my original post, this can be done by single line command. However, I am curious why the while loop is not working. The error message I've received is `basename: extra operand ':'`. Moreover, the command `grep -w -l "index123" */*.out` shows permission deny issue as because I am working in a server system with limited access. I need to look only within the working directory.

Comment: @Akand Well, if you look at what you actually get from your grep command, you will notice that there is a lot more than just the filename in the result. You are, for example requesting the line numbers... Also, I don't know how you're going to grep files in subdirectories without actually accessing the files in the subdirectories (they are there, not in the current directory).

Comment: For clarification: I am in the directory A from where the code will scan *.out file of every folders of A by searching the text "index123" and then will print out the corresponding folder names. I like to do it by while loop as shown in the original post.

Comment: @Akand See updated answer.

Comment: I appreciate your answer which does solve the problem. However, as mentioned in my post although there is solution of one line code, I like to do by `while` loop as I need to perform other operations.