# find a file through particular search in while loop

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep, scripting, find

Actually it is related to my previous post [sorting out directories by searching certain file extension](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/437118/sorting-out-directories-by-searching-certain-file-extension) which is still unanswered. There are many options available to solve the problem, but I am particularly interest via `while` loop. In a current working directory I want to search the existence of a particular file by scanning through certain content in a `while` loop and then print only the corresponding folder name. The current working directory has many folders and sub-folders. Here is my script:

```
while IFS= read -r d; do  
   if [[ "$d"=="*.out" && grep "index123"]]; then exit 1;  fi  
done <<  (find . -prune -type d)
```

I do not know whether imposing `if` is a right approach to do inside the loop or something else. Please guide.

Comment: You need spaces around your `==` and before `]]` like: `[[ "$d" == "*.out" && grep "index123" ]]`.  However the second part `grep "index123"` doesn't make sense.  Maybe you want `[[ "$d" == "*.out" && "$d" =~ index123 ]]`.  However overall I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: What is `grep "index123"` suppose to `grep` against? You typically do something like `echo $d | grep -q "index123"`.

Comment: The `*.out` file should have the text "index123". That is why I used `grep`. I am trying to find out the *.out file by searching through "index123" and then print the corresponding folder name in the mentioned `while` loop.

Comment: @Akand - but you're not presenting it to `grep` to see it. Try it in a shell `grep "index123"` in a terminal will just hang, it's hanging b/c you haven't told it what to `grep`.

Comment: `grep` from the file "*.out" which should have text "index123".

Comment: Is `*.out` supposed to match a directory or a file name? And is `index123` supposed to be from the _contents_ of a file or from a filename?

Comment: file name; yes, contents of a file

Comment: The question is unclear: Where is the keyword `index123` to be found? Is it part of a filename or found in the contents of some file. According to your own code, `*.out` should match directory names. Why do you use `-prune` like you do?

Comment: Your last comment clarifies nothing I'm afraid. You say `index123` should be found in a filename _and_ in the contents of a file?

Comment: "index123" is to be found in the file "*.out". If I understand well, `prune` here can be replaced as `-maxdepth 1`.

Comment: @Kusalananda, I have edited the post, and the question is solved.

Comment: @Kusalananda, it looks like my post still is on hold, I am not sure why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Why grep fails

Doing this in a terminal:

*Fails - Waiting for input*

```
$ grep "index123"
```

*Works - Receives input from STDIN*

```
$ echo -e "line1\nline2\nindex123blah\n" | grep "index123"
index123blah
```

The 2nd one works because we presented input for `grep` to parse via STDIN. `grep` will take input from either STDIN or a file. In your scenario:

```
if [[ "$d"=="*.out" && grep "index123"]]; then exit 1;  fi
```

It's not parsing either, hence it's failing.

#### Your issue

From the looks of your code I believe you want something like this. To start here's some sample data:

```
$ mkdir -p 1/2/{3..5}
$ echo "index123" > 1/2/3/blah.out
$ echo "index123" > 1/2/3/blip.out
$ echo "index" > 1/2/blip.out
$ echo "index" > 1/2/blah.out
```

And a modified form of your script:

```
$ cat loopy.bash
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r d; do  
  grep -l "index123" "$d" && exit 1
done < <(find . -type f -name "*.out")
```

Running:

```
$ ./loopy.bash
./1/2/3/blah.out
```

Emits the first file it found that has `index123` string, and exits.

#### While loop a good solution?

I wouldn't do it this way. Using a `while` loop here in this manner isn't necessary. It would be better to use a `find .... | xargs ...` architecture, or `find ... -exec` type of solution.

See [@DopeGhoti's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/457291/7453) for a better approach to using `find` with either `-exec` or `xargs`.

#### Printing containing directory

If you simply want to print the containing directory tree where the matching file resides, you can use `dirname` to do this like so:

```
$ cat loopy2.bash
#!/bin/bash

 while IFS= read -r d; do
   grep -q "index123" "$d" && dirname "$d"  && exit 1
 done < <(find . -type f -name "*.out")
```

And running it:

```
 $ ./loopy2.bash
./1/2/3
```

Comment: I think I got my solution. I do not need `exit 1` provided if I want to printout all folder paths. Also, I can use `cut` to get the folder names only. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem:

```
if [[ "$d"=="*.out" && grep "index123"]];
```

Let's pretend that `d=foo.out`.  We effectively now have:

```
if [[ grep "index123"]];
```

So you're trying to tell `grep` to search standard input for the expression `/index123/`.  But there would be no input coming to it, so it would (appear to) hang while it waits for input. **However**, it won't even get that far because `if [[ grep "index123" ]]` is invalid syntax on its face.  You'd instead want `if grep "index123"`.  But again -- that will simply wait for standard input to come in.

It appears that you want to the returns from `find` for files named `*.out` which contain the text `index123`.  So try this:

```
find . -prune -type d -name \*.out -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l 'index123'
```

That `find` statement is rather convoluted, though.  Why `find` everything and then prune the directories when we could just search for the actual files we want?

```
find . -type f -name \*.out -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l 'index123'
```

Now you will see any files which contain the text for which you seek.

We don't even need to bring `xargs` to the table though, as `find` can invoke `grep` on its own:

```
find . -type f -name \*.out -exec grep -l 'index123' "{}" \;
```

Comment: `[[ grep ... ]]` will not call grep.

Comment: As mentioned, how to solve through the `while` loop?

Comment: @Akand What if a while loop reading the output of `find` is not a good solution?

Comment: Good catch on the blatant syntax error, @Kusalananda.  It must be Thursday; I never could get the hang of Thursdays.  I've addressed that in my recent edit.

Comment: Good question! What is alternative solution if not using `find` in the `while` loop? I want to print the folder name after the searching within the while loop.

Comment: Do you want _only_ the directory name, or the filename as well?  This solution will provide e. g. `./path/to/location/containing/filename.out`.

Comment: @Akand - see my update, I show how to print the directory.

Answer (score 1):

Finding all `*.out` files that contain the string `index123` in the current directory:

```
grep -lF 'index123' ./*.out
```

If you want to do a recursive `grep` on all `*.out` files regardless of where they are beneath the current directory:

```
find . -type f -name '*.out' -exec grep -lF 'index123' {} +
```

Printing the directory where the string has been found:

```
find . -type f -name '*.out' -exec grep -qF 'index123' {} ';' -exec dirname {} ';'
```

Quitting after first found directory name (using GNU `find`):

```
find . -type f -name '*.out' -exec grep -qF 'index123' {} ';' -exec dirname {} ';' -quit
```

Depending on what you then are planning to *use* the directory name for, you would replace the `-quit` with another `-exec` to process the directory in whatever way you need to, alternatively combine the various `-exec` utilities into a shell script called from `-exec`.  What you're *not* doing is to pipe the directory name to some other command, as that is generally unsafe unless you take extra precautions in delimiting the pathname(s) with nul characters.

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)
- [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697)

Comment: This Q is a pile.